# Unable to access source maps in Sentry for Ionic application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, sentry

I've build my Ionic project with:
`ionic build --prod --source-map`

Then I've uploaded the sourcemaps with:
`npx sentry-cli releases files my-app-1.1.0 upload-sourcemaps ../sentry-source-code-1.1.0 --url-prefix 'http://localhost'`
(the sentry-source-code-1.1.0 folder contains the .map and .js files)

Issues show up on Sentry.io but I got this error:
[image]

Which seems to make sense, but unfortunately Ionic / Capacitor apps are always loaded from `localhost` since it is a Webview container.

These files do exist in Sentry's release artifacts as well:
[image]

Uploading without `--url-prefix 'http://localhost` did not change anything

How can I tell sentry to lookup the `localhost` files and sourcemaps in the artifacts?

Comment: How are you uploading the sourcemaps? What version of the SDK are you using? Sentry have docs on this particular case in here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/cordova/sourcemaps/ and there's a new Cordova SDK if you'd like to try: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cordova/releases

Comment: @BrunoGarcia I upload with de Sentry cli with the command shown in my question. I think the SDK shouldn't be the problem since I can see my errors. I use the `sentry/browser` package v5.30.0

Comment: @BasvanDijk I'm running into the same exact issue. Did you find anything that works?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I did, it turned out that the issue was related to accidentally create two Sentry instances. Therefore the wrong version number and app name was mapped to the artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it happens because you pass `--url-prefix localhost`.

Try removing it.

Comment: I've should had added that this didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Prefix has to include a `~/` which is protocol matcher. Ditch `http://` from the prefix and use `~/localhost` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've used `npx sentry-cli releases files my-app-1.1.0 upload-sourcemaps ../sentry-source-code-1.1.0 --url-prefix '~/localhost'` without luck. The artifacts are listed as `~/localhost/16-es2015.9f2ea41f96c1922da4bc.js`

Comment: And this should be enough. Feel free to reach out and send me a link to the unresolved event either through Discord (link can be found in our sentry-javascript repo) or through any other communication channel (can be found in my GH profile), and I'll take a look.

Comment: I've send you an email with more info